# iOS best slideshow practice on multiple devices

Tags: ios, uiimageview, slideshow

I have created the following code for all iOS devices. It detects the screen size and use the appropriate images for each devices sizes. While this works it is far from ideal. For each image I need to save it into 5 different sizes. What is a better way to do this? Should I basically have a background(which is repeating), a small icon in the center and some text. Can I just produce the text with the correct size font and use separate image view sizes instead of having 40+ images. If this is the way I should do it... how can I make the background image view flow over the edge of the screen without stretching the background image and making it look distorted? Are there better options?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIButton *beginIntro = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [beginIntro addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(begin:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [beginIntro setTitle:@"Begin Intro" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    beginIntro.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 310.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [[self view] addSubview:beginIntro];

    UIButton *reset = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [beginIntro addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(reset:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [reset setTitle:@"Reset Intro" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    reset.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 410.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [[self view] addSubview:reset];

    _SlideImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].origin.x, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].origin.y, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height)];
    [[self view]addSubview:_SlideImageView];
    [self setSlideNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
}
-(IBAction)begin:(id)sender{
    if ([_SlideNumber intValue] <=8) {

        UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self getSlideShowImageName]];
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                          duration:5.0f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{
                            self.SlideImageView.image = toImage;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            sleep(2);
                            [self begin:nil];
                        }];


        int SlideNumber = [_SlideNumber intValue];
        int NewSlideNumber = SlideNumber+=1;
        [self setSlideNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NewSlideNumber]];
    }

}
-(NSString*)getSlideShowImageName{
    NSString * slideShowImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

        if (scale > 1.0)
        {
            //iPad retina screen
            slideShowImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipad%d@2x.png",[_SlideNumber intValue]];
        }
        else
        {
            //iPad screen
            slideShowImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipad%d.png",[_SlideNumber intValue]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        {
            CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

            if (scale > 1.0)
            {
                if([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568)
                {
                    //iphone 5
                    slideShowImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iphone5%d.png",[_SlideNumber intValue]];
                }
                else
                {
                    //iphone retina screen
                    slideShowImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iphoneipod%d@2x.png",[_SlideNumber intValue]];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //iphone screen
                slideShowImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iphoneipod%d.png",[_SlideNumber intValue]];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"slideShowImageName : %@",slideShowImageName);
    return slideShowImageName;
}
-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender{
    [self setSlideNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    [self begin:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your background pattern image 'repeat' to fill the entire screen, create a `UIColor` with the background pattern image, and set the view background color to that color. For example:

```
UIColor *myBackgroundPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackgroundPatternImageFilename"]];
myView.backgroundColor = myBackgroundPattern;
```

Note that you do not need to add the extension if the image file is png.

**Edit:**

To use a single image to fill the background without "stretching":

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBackgroundImageFilename"];
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Assuming the image is at least as large as the largest device display, it will be centered and clipped to the bounds of the myImageView.

Comment: its not a repeating pattern to that extent it's a countertop so same look but it wont match i basically want the ipad retina image just to be dropped onto all the other sides and for it to just ignore what goes off screen.

Comment: OK, to just use a single image in all cases then set the view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeCenter` which centers the image, and clips to the view's bounds.